# Mysql select query is not showing result if the search value is small letter

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql table I've a `file_content` column which contain resume text. In my search form I'm searching this resume text using following mysql query.

For example : I've a text in my db table column  is like this :

```
SUMMARY IS start here.
```

NOW if i put the **summary** in serach field it's not showing the result but If I use **SUMMARY** then it's showing the result.

It's look like sql case sensitivity problem. I don't know exactly. Can anyone tell me how do i fix this search query so that it will result any data whatever the value it is like: capital or small letter.

```
if(!empty($ad_resume)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND BINARY LOCATE('$ad_resume', contact_docs.file_content)"; //is this the resume? yes
}
```

Comment: @Strawberry Remove the BINARY is not working, is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to set/override the collation for the query to one that supports case insensitivity

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: What is query should be In this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It's was mysql table column data type problem. if I use text, longtext data type then it's working because it's non-binary data type :)